# Cryptic Error Message from Scikit Learn Svm Fit

Tags: python, image-recognition, scikit-learn, handwriting, svm

I am attempting to train a support vector machine with scikit learn using [these docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html) but I am getting an error message I do not understand.  Am I doing something wrong?

Here is my script.  The idea is I have a file where each line is of the form "label data".  The data is a string of zeros and ones.

svm-learn.py

```
import os
import re
from sklearn import svm

classifier = svm.SVC()

data = open("sd19-train-binary.txt", "r")

labels = []
training_data = [] 
i = 0

for line in data:
    match = re.search("^(\S+) (\d+)", line)
    label = match.group(1)
    vector = list(match.group(2))
    vector = [int(x) for x in vector]
    labels.append(label)
    training_data.append([vector])
    i += 1
    if i > 100:
        break

classifier.fit(training_data, labels)
```

When I run it, this happens:

```
$ python svm-learn.py
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "svm-learn.py", line 26, in <module>
      classifier.fit(training_data, labels)
    File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scikit_learn-0.14_git-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg/sklearn/svm/base.py", line 184, in fit
      fit(X, y, sample_weight, solver_type, kernel)
    File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scikit_learn-0.14_git-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg/sklearn/svm/base.py", line 228, in _dense_fit
      max_iter=self.max_iter)
    File "libsvm.pyx", line 53, in sklearn.svm.libsvm.fit (sklearn/svm/libsvm.c:1660)
  ValueError: Buffer has wrong number of dimensions (expected 2, got 3)
```

A single line in my input file looks like this:

```
W 1111111111111100001111111100011111111111100011111110011111000111111111110111111111
```

This is for glyph recognition on the nist special database 19

Answer (score 0):

Fixed, problem was in the append.  Should be

```
training_data.append(vector)
```

instead of

```
training_data.append([vector])
```